# How to change title bar color of emacs in gnome desktop environment

Tags: gnome, emacs, theme

I'm using Gentoo with gnome-42.3. I've set the theme to `Adwaita-dark`. All the windows turned dark except the `emacs`. Is there a way to set title-bar-color for a specific application?

Answer (score 0):

restarting the PC turned the emacs titlebar to dark.